# "There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Item1" error when using dropdownbutton in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the dropdown menu in my flutter app but getting an error.

**Here is the code:**

```
List<String> items = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"];
String selectedItem = "Item1";
DropdownButton<String>(
  items: items.map(
    (txt) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        child: Text(
          "$txt"
        ),
      );
    }
  ).toList(),
  value: selectedItem,
)
```

In some questions, I saw that we have to initially set a variable to the value present inside our list. I have exactly done that but still getting an error.

**Error Message:**

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Item1. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 850 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

What is the error here?

Kindly comment if more information is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here an example, the explanation in the code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<String> items = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"];
  String selectedItem = "Item1";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        children: [

          Flex(direction: Axis.vertical, children:[
            DropdownButton<String>(
              value: selectedItem,
              onChanged: (itemValue) {  // update the selectedItem value
                setState(() {
                  selectedItem = itemValue!;
                });
              },
              items: items
                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value, // add this property an pass the value to it
                  child: Text(value,)
              )).toList(),
            ),
          ])

        ],
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> items = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"];
String selectedItem = "";
DropdownButton<String>(
  items: items.map(
    (txt) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        child: Text("$txt"),
      );
    }
  ).toList(),
  value: selectedItem==""null?"":selectedItem,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the list from an api that returns list, look at what i did to debug the error.

1. Created a reusable widget that handle future response

   ```
    Widget rangeLists(selectedValue) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: YourFuture,//this should return Future<List>
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text('Loading...');
          } else {
            List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> categoriesItems = [
              DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(selectedValue),
                value: selectedValue,
              ),
            ];
            print('categoriesItems.last.value');
            print(categoriesItems.last.value);
            var snapshotAsMap = snapshot.data as List;
            for (int i = 0; i < snapshotAsMap.length; i++) {
              if (snapshotAsMap[i]['category'] != selectedValue) {
                categoriesItems.add(
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text(snapshotAsMap[i]['category']),
                    value: snapshotAsMap[i]['category'],
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0, right: 18, top: 10),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  items: categoriesItems,
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.expand_more,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  iconSize: 24,
                  elevation: 16,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  underline: SizedBox(),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.selectedValue = value;
                    });
                  },
                  value: selectedValue,
                  hint: Text('My courses'),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        })};
   ```

2.Usage
you can called it like this

```
String selectedValue="Select Here"

rangeLists(selectedValue)//call this as a widget in ur ui
```

It will handle all list from the backend u don't need to worry about the error any more